# BindingSource cancel AddingNew

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, bindingsource

Is it possible to cancel adding an item inside `BindingSource.AddingNew` event handler?

When user clicks on the "Add new" button in my `BindingNavigator`, I am opening a dialog which may or may not return a valid file. Right now, I have something like this:

```
void bindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    using (var dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        // user canceled?
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;

        // TryLoad will return null on failure
        var data = TryLoad(dialog.FileName);

        // only add the item to the grid if not null
        if (data != null)
            e.NewObject = data;
    }
}
```

Even if I don't set `e.NewObject` to a value inside the handler, a new ("empty") item appears in the DataGridView.

Is it possible to cancel adding the item?

Comment: if you do not set `e.NewObject` it creates one for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution:

1. Clear the BindingNavigator "AddNewItem" property in Properties window, so that it doesn't fire bindingsource AddingNew.
2. Double click on the plus sign in bindingNavigator to generate Click event for the plus button and manually control add new item procedure, like the following:

   ```
   private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       using (var dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
       {
           if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
           {
               var data = TryLoad(dialog.FileName); ;

               if (data != null)
               {
                   myBindingSource.Add(data);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. Simple, no reflection, does what's intended. I had no idea that these properties exist. Great!

Answer (score 5):

If your BindingSource implements the [ICancelAddNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icanceladdnew.aspx) interface you should be able to call CancelNew on the newly added object to revert it.  I would not suggest attempting this in the event handler for AddNew.  By having this interface your item will still be added to the list, but in a pending state where EndNew() will commit the transaction and CancelNew() will revert the transaction.  It looks like the [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) implements ICancelNew and would allow you to do something like:

```
public void MyFunctionWhereIAddNew()
{
    var item  = _myBindingSource.AddNew();

    item.SetSomeParams(...);

    if(item.CheckItemForSuccess() != true)
    {
        _myBindingSource.CancelNew(_myBindingSource.IndexOf(item));
    }
}
```

If you want a link on how to go about implementing your own ICancelNew check out [this old blog post](http://www.teamjohnston.net/blogs/jesse/2006/12/default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. But if I am adding the row through a `BindingNavigator` (I am not calling `AddNew` from code), I am only getting the `AddingNew` event fired.

Comment: How are you adding the event listener for the AddingNew event?  How do you create the BindingSource for your BindingNavigator?

Comment: I use a list as the datasource for the BindingSource: `List<T> list = GetData(); bindingSource.DataSource = list;`, and I use the BindingSource as the data source for grid and navigator: `dataGridView.DataDource = bindingSource; bindingNavigator.DataSource = bindingSource;`. This gives me grid + navigator functionality out of the box, but there is no way to cancel adding, once user hits the "Add" button on the BindingNavigator control.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but in a **very** ugly way. You must override click event of add button of `BindingNavigator`. Solution provided below test and works, but obviously not good for any production systems. I have one code like this in a production system to reorder event handlers. I do not like it but it works.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public MethodInfo refreshMethod;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Build Data
        var list = new List<MyData>
            {
                new MyData {Id = 1, Str = "1"},
                new MyData {Id = 2, Str = "2"}
            };

        //Bind Data
        bindingSource1.DataSource = list;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindingSource1;

        // get event handler storage property
        var eventsProperty = bindingNavigator1.AddNewItem.GetType().GetProperty(
            "Events",
            BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
            );

        // get key for click event
        var clickField = bindingNavigator1.AddNewItem.GetType().GetField(
            "EventClick",
            BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static
            );

        var clickKey = clickField.GetValue(null);

        // find refresh method
        refreshMethod = bindingNavigator1.GetType().GetMethod(
            "RefreshItemsInternal",
            BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
            );

        // get storage instance
        var handlers = (EventHandlerList)eventsProperty.GetValue(bindingNavigator1.AddNewItem, null);
        // find click event handlers
        var clickEventHandlers = handlers[clickKey];

        // remove current handlers
        var handlerInvocationList = clickEventHandlers.GetInvocationList();
        for (int index = 0; index < handlerInvocationList.Length; index++)
            handlers.RemoveHandler(clickKey, handlerInvocationList[index]);

        // attach our new handler
        handlers.AddHandler(clickKey, new EventHandler(NewAddNewHandler));
    }

    private void NewAddNewHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bindingNavigator1.Validate() && null != bindingNavigator1.BindingSource)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Add new?", "Are you..", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes;

            if (!result)
                return;

            bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.AddNew();
            refreshMethod.Invoke(bindingNavigator1, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution that definatly needs some additions before i would make it into anything productionlike is to cancel the edit in bindingnavigators *AddNew* click event.

You do need to set a boolean value in bindingSource_AddingNew(..) that indicates if canceling the edit is what you want to do.

```
     
private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if(cancelEdit)
        bindingSource.CancelEdit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you handle the add with a button? If so, you can set the button click event to check all your parameters before ever calling the Add method of the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing a dialog form for both adding or editing data from a table from some datasource you can simply use `BindingSource.CancelEdit()` function at any time you need to cancel adding a new row and use `BindingSource.EndEdit()` to accept and end editing entered data which are valid to be uploaded on your database for example use these lines of codes in add/edit dialog form (which its textboxes are binded to contactsBindingSource):

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    contactsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    contactsTableAdapter.Update(contactsTable)
    contactsTable = contactsTableAdapter.GetData()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    contactsBindingSource.CancelEdit()
    contactsTable = contactsTableAdapter.GetData()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to override AddNew method in a class inherited from BindingSource.

```
public override object AddNew() {
{
  if (CreateNewItem( out newItem))
  {
    base.Add(newItem);
    return newItem;
  }
  return null;
}
```